# Blocked Source of HTML Video Element Fails to Trigger Error Event

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm embedding a video on one page that is only accessible if the user is logged in on a different domain.  IF they're not logged in, I'd like to listen for an error event and change the  element to an  link to the login page.  Unfortunately, neither the .mediafallbacklink nor [an event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) is working correctly.  Only a disabled video player is shown.  **Any ideas?**

In testing, the embed element is on `localhost:1337` and the video source is on `localhost`.

```
<video data-setup-lazy="{&quot;language&quot;: &quot;en&quot;, &quot;fluid&quot;: true}" class="video-js" preload="auto" controls="true" title="Export Compliance">
  <source src="http://localhost/pluginfile.php/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <a class="mediafallbacklink" href="http://localhost/pluginfile.php/myvideo.mp4">Video Source</a>
</video>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  console.log("this works:", document.querySelector("video"));
  document.querySelector("video").onerror = function(event) {
    console.log("but this never fires:", event);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = this.src;
    a.innerHTML = "Video Source";
    a.download = videoPlayer.src;
    this.parentElement.replaceChild(a, this);
  };
});
```

This error is shown in the JavaScript console (Chrome 60):

```
GET http://localhost/pluginfile.php/myvideo.mp4 
net::ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`video` tag doesn't fire an `error` event if it can not find the specified URL.
Instead you should listen to the `<source>` tag inside the `<video>` tag for the `error` event like below.

```js
$("video source").on("error", function(e) {
  alert(e.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="video" data-setup-lazy="{&quot;language&quot;: &quot;en&quot;, &quot;fluid&quot;: true}" class="video-js" preload="auto" controls="true" title="Export Compliance">
  <source src="http://localhost/pluginfile.php/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <a class="mediafallbacklink" href="http://localhost/pluginfile.php/myvideo.mp4">Video Source</a>
</video>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.